# Memory error while predicting in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Following is the piece of code that I wrote to get feature selection using RFE and estimator LinearSVC and then using the reduced data to fit and predict KNeighborClassifier.

```
    clf = LinearSVC(C = 10, class_weight = 'auto')
    rfe = RFE(estimator = clf, n_features_to_select = 700, step = 42)
    rfe.fit(X, trainLabels)
    reduced_train_data = rfe.transform(X)
    print "reduced_train_data.shape ", reduced_train_data.shape
    reduced_test_data = rfe.transform(test)
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='distance', algorithm = 'ball_tree')
    print "knn initiated"
    neigh.fit(reduced_train_data, trainLabels)
    print "knn fitted"
    test_predict = neigh.predict(reduced_test_data)
    print "knn predicted"
```

Following is the output:
reduced_train_data.shape  (42000, 700)
knn initiated
knn fitted

And then I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Coursera\KaggleDataProjects\DigitRecognition\main.py", line 74, in <module>
    test_predict = neigh.predict(reduced_test_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\classification.py", line 146, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 313, in kneighbors
    return_distance=return_distance)
  File "binary_tree.pxi", line 1295, in sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.query (sklearn\neighbors\ball_tree.c:9889)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 91, in array2d
    X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 320, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
MemoryError
```

This error does not happen everytime I run the code by slightly changing the parameter. Can some one please explain what needs to be done to fix this problem.

Initial dimension of train data (X) = 42000, 784
Initial dimension of test data (test) = 28000, 784

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? The ball tree class has been rewritten in 0.14. If you are using the latest release then this is probably a bug. Feel free to report it to https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

Comment: I am using 0.14.1 version.

Comment: At that scale, RFE is not a good idea. It works well at small scales, but can take a lot of memory.

Comment: Which algorithms would be good for feature selection at that scale?

Comment: I would try [Chi2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2) on samples of the dataset.